# Retrieve the Webview's request's headers

Tags: android, html, apache, http

i am working on an android web client that uses a WebView to display webpages.

What i am trying to achieve is this.

When i call webView.loadDataWithBaseURL i want to somehow get the headers that the Webview generates and uses. right now i could not find a webView.getHeaders or anything from a webViewClient which acts as a callback to a webView.

This implementation exists in iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/URLOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001834-BAJEAIEE and i am wondering if it is possible in android/java?

When a user navigates to some authentication login webpage, i need to get the Headers.

any suggestions?